# Apache user permission

Tags: php, python, apache, permissions

I have an Apache server installed which exposes a website written in PHP that I have been working on. One of the functions of the website is to insert new data into a MySQL database. When data is to be inserted the user presses a link which in turn calls a PHP script which contains a line like this

```
$script_return = exec('python some_script.py);
```

the python script generates a number of files in the root of the root directory of the site. After creation of these files the script names them after a specific system and moves them to subfolders (via shutil). When I run the script manually everything works fine. When I, however, try to run is from the website the files are created but they are not moved. Both the .php script and the .py script have 777 right and belongs to the www-data group but it still does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the www-data user may not have the right permissions in your destination folders.  If Apache can create the files, it should have rights to move the files.

Why not create the files directly in the location that you want them?  That will also give you a more specific error about what's going wrong.

You could also have the python script write a log file somewhere that you can check after.

Once you've got it sorted, I would recommend removing 777 permissions.

Comment: The python scripts executes yet another terminal command which creates the files (a command I have no direct control of). The output files is hence created in the root directory by default - something which I cannot change. I simply do no understand how can the www-data user have privileges to create files but not move them? The destination directory also have 777 while testing.